# Designing a factory framework with Guice, enumerations, and static factory methods

Tags: java, subclass, guice, factory, enumeration

Consider a scenario where I want to take a `String data` with some data and parse it into a certain kind of object, say `Animal`. **Disclaimer:** Even though it's long, this is an sscce; my actual project has little to do with cat sounds :)

Requirements:

- The first character indicates the "type of the animal". So `C` might refer to `abstract class Cat`, and `D` might refer to `abstract class Dog`.
- The second character optionally indicates the "subtype of the animal"... except these subtypes are grouped into categories (as far as classes go). So a `CS` might be `ThaiCat extends Cat` with argument `"Siamese"` and `CK` might be a `ThaiCat extends Cat` with argument `"Korat"`, and `CB` might be `AmericaCat extends Cat` with argument `Bengal`
- The `data` `String` has other information in it. For example, it might have the name of the Animal. Don't worry about how to parse this data, this code would be shared between the `abstract class` (which can parse the things that are true for all `Cat` subtypes, and the subclass will parse out the rest of the needed data).

First solution, start with this:

```
public enum AnimalType {
  CAT ('C') { Animal makeAnimal(String data) { return CatType.makeCat(data); },
  DOG ('D') { Animal makeAnimal(String data) { return DogType.makeDog(data); };
  private char type;
  public char getType() { return type; }
  private AnimalType(char type) { this.type = type; }
  abstract Animal makeAnimal(String data);

  private static Map<Character, AnimalType> animalMap = new HashMap<>();
  static {
    for(AnimalType currentType : AnimalType.values()) {
      animalMap.put(currentType.getType(), currentType());
    }
  }
  public static Animal makeAnimal(String data) {
    return animalMap.get(data.charAt(0)).makeAnimal(data);
  }
}

public enum CatType {
  BENGAL ('B') { Cat makeCat(String data) { return new AmericaCat(data, this) },
  RAGDOLL ('R') { Cat makeCat(String data) { return new AmericaCat(data, this) },
  KORAT ('K') { Cat makeCat(String data) { return new ThaiCat(data, this) },
  SIAMESE ('S') { Cat makeCat(String data) { return new ThaiCat(data, this) };

  private char type;
  public char getType() { return type; }
  private CatType(char type) { this.type = type; }
  abstract Cat makeCat(String data, CatType type);

  private static Map<Character, CatType> catMap = new HashMap<>();
  static {
    for(CatType currentType : CatType.values()) {
      catMap.put(currentType.getType(), currentType());
    }
  }
  static Cat makeCat(String data) {
    return catMap.get(data.charAt(1)).makeCat(data);
  }
}
```

This is all well and good, it should be fast and clean, proper code delegation, etc. HOWEVER. Now what if suddenly animals have dependencies (I am using Guice)? Say I have a library with animal sounds, and I want to be able to do `animal.speak()` and the functionality of calling the sound object is encapsulated within the `Animal`.

Here are some things I've considered:

- Use `MapBinder` to set up the `Enum` -> `Cat` subclass pairings. Then bind the `Map<K, Provider<V>>` map into a factory class, and pass the `data` into the the `Cat` object as a method call after creation
- Create an AssistedInject factory, and have each enumeration's `makeCat` method call the correct method in the factory. The problem is, I can't inject a factory into an Enumeration instance, and Guice recommends not using static injections. Thus, I have to pass my factory all the way down the method chain, which seems to defeat the purpose. Also, this doesn't solve the problem of disallowing the wrong constructor to be called by the wrong String.
- Create a manual factory object. Though I'm not sure how much of the work should be done by the factory and how much by the enumeration (if any).

What's the best solution?

Comment: I vote for the nested maps; AnimalMap->CatMap->TypeOfCatConstructor.  Catception?  I suspect this may be closed for being an open ended question.

Comment: @Aggieboy I could have just posted "how to can you use AssistedInject when you need static factory method functionality?" But such short questions are frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

You've got two problems here, really:

1. How to give Guice the input needed to decide what kind of object to make
2. How to get Guice to run the code to make the right object

#### Problem 1.

Guice *really really wants* to just make a big graph of objects on startup using information provided at startup-time.  Yet a lot of what makes it powerful comes from giving it the ability to vary its behavior depending on conditions at runtime - so a lot of frameworks that build on Guice do things to enable that - Servlet support has its *request scope* which lets a servlet request be injected, and so forth.

There are three basic ways to give objects created on-the-fly to Guice to use when creating objects:

- [Assisted Inject](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AssistedInject)
- [Custom scopes](https://github.com/timboudreau/scopes)
- Write a one-off `Provider<Animal>` which gets hold of the relevant data somehow (typically using a `ThreadLocal` - custom scopes are typically a generalization of this pattern) and creates the right object

#### Problem 2.

Assuming the input is provided on-the-fly at runtime, and assuming you have a factory, or provider which will create the right object, you need to either convince Guice to give that object to your code, or you need to create some alternative path for the information to take to get the data.

The usual way is with a `ThreadLocal` - i.e. before making a call which could trigger instantiation of an `Animal` you would set the `ThreadLocal` to contain the string you want to parse;  if something actually needs one, your parsing code will be invoked.  If you find the use of a `ThreadLocal` distasteful, you can implement Scope (or use a library that does, like the one linked above) - but typically it's just using a `ThreadLocal` under-the-hood.

Here's a simplified example of what all of that would look like:

```
public class App {
  public interface Animal {
  }
  private static class Cat implements Animal {
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadLocal<String> theData = new ThreadLocal<>();
    MyModule module = new MyModule(theData);
    Injector inj = Guice.createInjector(module);
    // Try a test run
    theData.set("Cat thing");
    try {
      Animal animal = inj.getInstance(Animal.class);
      assert animal instanceof Cat;
      System.out.println("Got " + animal);
    } finally {
      theData.remove();
    }
  }

  private static class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    private final ThreadLocal<String> data;
    public MyModule(ThreadLocal<String> data) {
      this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
      bind(new TypeLiteral<ThreadLocal<String>>() {
      }).toInstance(data);
      bind(Animal.class).toProvider(AnimalProvider.class);
    }
  }

  private static class AnimalProvider implements Provider<Animal> {
    private final ThreadLocal<String> data;
    @Inject
    public AnimalProvider(ThreadLocal<String> data) {
      this.data = data;
    }

    public Animal get() {
      String providedAtRuntime = data.get();
      assert providedAtRuntime != null;
      switch (providedAtRuntime.charAt(0)) {
        case 'C':
          return new Cat();
        // ...
        default:
          throw new IllegalArgumentException(providedAtRuntime);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The last thing to think about is how your Animal instances get created.  If the number of animals is small and finite, and Animal objects are stateless, you might just iterate all the possible combinations and create all of them on startup, and then you're just doing a simple lookup.  Or you could parse the input and make that decision on-the-fly - depends what you need.

#### To Enum or not to Enum

I would recommend against using Enums for this stuff - you'll find that sooner or later you want to implement an `Animal` which wrappers another `Animal` and delegates to that, or something similar, and you can't create enum instances on-the-fly.

What you can do instead is have an Animal *interface*, and then an enum which implements that interface - that way you get the flexibility of an interface and can use enums for the common case - just write all of your code to the interface, not the enum.

If you really, really need to restrict some code to take only enum-instances of Animal, you can do that without tying that code to a specific enum:

`public <A extends Animal & Enum<A>> void foo(A animal) { ... }`

which gives you all the benefits of enums while still writing code which can be reused on new enums in the future.

Comment: I just quickly skimmed this, I'll reread it more carefully in a moment. But in the real situation, the number of `Animal`s and `Cat` subtypes etc. is fixed and will 99.9% never change; but the created objects are NOT stateless. So a hypothetical input string might be: `"CS;Kittykat;40cm;Brown-Black"` etc., and you might have another one `"CS;Meowth;37cm;Tan"` or something.

Comment: Yes, okay, I read this more carefully, and familiarized myself with `ThreadLocal` - this is not really appropriate for my situation. The types of objects are very fixed, but the kinds of data that can populate their instances are very not-fixed. I'm currently doing a solution with AssistedInject that is not particularly clean, but works. I might change it if someone comes around to this thread with a better answer.